# Number of groups of order $p^n$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

for $n=1$, it is cyclic. so, the number is $1$

for $n=2$, it is Abelian. so, the number is $2$

for $n\geq 3$, I don't know.

Can you recommend a book or link which can be helpful for understanding this?

Not just the result. I want to know the process of proving

Comment: I don't know if the number $f(n)$ of non isomorphic groups of order  $p^n$ has a known closed formula, but you can classify them inductively, I guess. As the center is non trivial in those groups (because they are $p$-groups), one can quotient by the center to obtain a group of order $p^m$ where $m<n$ and go on with the classification of the previous stages. The case $n=3$ is easy to do with this technique.

Comment: You are wondering how many groups of order $p^n$ there are? It is a famous conjecture that "almost all" groups are of order $2^n$ for some $n$. The answer to your question is therefore "lots". There is a nice asymptotic formula though: see [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30358/number-of-non-abelian-groups-of-order-2n). Also, for $p$-groups I found the book of Leedham-Green and McKay *The Structure of Groups of Prime Power Order* to be useful, but it is not a simple text.

Comment: What exactly was the homework problem?

Comment: I suspect the homework problem was for abelian groups. Else the problem was suggested by a very evil professor.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I doubt that it is for abelian groups, as the post points out that groups of order $p^2$ are abelian. I wonder if was is simply "work it out for $n=1$ and $n=2$" (perhaps also $n=3$) and then the OP got curious. That said, I wonder if the OP knows the proof that a group of order $p^2$ is abelian? Is that perhaps what they are asking? Why knows....

Answer (score 5):

You should see "Enemuration of Finite Groups" by P. M. Neumann et al.

The general problem does not seem to be approachable, and a tremendous effort is done mainly by M. F. Newman, E. obrien, B. Eick, M. R. Vaughan-Lee, Hans Ulrich Besche and many others, just for settling some special cases.

It is known that the number of groups of order $p^n$ (let us denote it by $f(p,n)$) depends also on $p$, not only on $n$.

The explicit formula of $f(p,n)$ is known just for very small values of $n$:
$f(p,3)=5$, $f(p,4)=15$ for $p$ odd, and $f(2,4)=14$.

The situation become more complicated  for $n=5$, the exact formula is : $f(p,5)=2p+61+(4,p-1)+2(3,p-1)$ for $p>3$.

Still more and more complicated for $n=6$: $f(p,6)=3p^2+39p+344+24(3,p-1)+11(4,p-1)+2(5,p-1)$
for $p>3$.

A formula of $f(p,7)$, $p>5$ can be found as the main theorem in http://www.ukma.kiev.ua/~osp/GroupTheory/GroupsP%5E7/paper-p7.pdf

You should see the small groups library for other particular values and more references (for instance http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/small/).

A famous conjecture of G. Higman asserts that $f(p,n)$, when $n$ is fixed, is determined by a finite family of polynomials $(P_i)$, the choice of the polynomial $P_i$ (that is   $f(p,n)=P_i(p)$) depends on the residue of $p$  modulo some fixed integer $N$. Such a function is called PORC (polynomial on residue classes), so Higman's conjecture asserts that $f(p,n)$, as a function of $p$, is PORC.

On the other hand, if we fix $p$, we have the following asymptotic formula  for $f(p,n)$ (due to Higman and Sims): 
$f(p,n)=p^{2/27n^3+O(n^2)}$.